# export postgres db with pg_dump doesn't work, database "db_name" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

im trying to export PostgreSQL Databases (db name ari_company) using pg_dump command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin>pg_dump --no-owner -U postgres ari_company> dump.sql
```

and then i got this error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "ari_company" failed: FATAL:  database "ari_company" does not exist
```

but when i run for default database (postgres) it works and dump.sql is created.
with command

```
psql\l
```

i checked which db exist and there is postgres and my created ari_company. what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: So what exactly does `\l` show you when you run it in `psql`? ([edit] your question)

Comment: hi, i just found what was the problem. i had two servers instaled but somehow i was connecting to a wrong server (where there was no needed db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was that i had two installed server but was connecting to wrong server where there is no named database. databse postgres exits on both server because it's created automatically with name like you set for username